# IIS URL Rewrite: Match subdomain and redirect to HTTPS

Tags: iis, rewrite, redirection

Suppose the website URL is `subdomain.company.com`

I want to redirect the user to `https://subdomain.company.com` **only if**

1. The original request is not using `https`
2. subdomain matches `subdomain.comapny.com`

Relative URL and query string should append as expected.

I cannot edit web.config. So I have to do this via IIS only.

In IIS, I have tried the following but it is not giving desired results-

[image]

[image]

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Do you only want to redirect the one subdomain?

Comment: Yes only one subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Match URL" pattern is where you want to define `subdomain.company.com`.  Your "Conditions" pattern should be `off`, because you want to redirect when `{HTTPS}` is off. Also, if this is a permanent redirect, you may as well change the "Action" to `Permanent (301)`.